# Android SQL: How to check existing users?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am making an android app, and atm I do not know if my database was created I have checked my Logcat and I dont see any indication if my registeration has been added but it displays the toast of "Successfully registered"

I checked DDMS File explorer, it does not display database but Ive read some may not show it but anyways I want to check if it was added by adding a check existing username.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the username is unique, you need to query for the user row whose username is equal to the username you want to get:

```
public boolean exits(String username){
   boolean exists=false;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReradableDatabase();

   Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+help.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+help.COLUMN_USERNAME+" ='"+username+"' ;";

     if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) exists=true;
     cursor.close();
     db.close();

     return exists;
}
```

Ok, so in order to check if the user not exists and register it, you need to do the following into your onClick Method:

```
if (!password.equals(confirm)) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return;
} 
else if (handler.exists(name)){
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 return;
}
else {

    handler.addUser(name, username, password);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to invoke a rawQuery on your database to fetch the row with a specific username:

```
public boolean exists(String username){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = ? LIMIT 1",
            help.COLUMN_NAME, help.TABLE_NAME, help.COLUMN_NAME),
            new String[] { username });

    return c.moveToFirst();
}
```

This will return `true` if a user with such name exists and false otherwise.

**Response to your comment:**

```
...
else if (handler.exists(username))  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This username already taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
} else {
    handler.addUser(name, username, password);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: From the raw Query, when the user types in the registertation Username text field "Student" for example and fills the rest of the form, when the user clicks crete account button. How can I implement that in the registration.java to compare

Comment: @LearnFred just add another `else if` block. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks looking at the raw query there is an error on it, got this error:

 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT TOP 1 name FROM USERS WHERE name = ?

Comment: @LearnFred ahh it seems that TOP is not a valid keyword in sqlite. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isRecordExist(String value) {
        boolean exist = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;
        if (value != null) {
            sql = sql + " where <coloumn_name> = '" + value + "'";
        }
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.getCount() > 0)
                exist = true;
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return exist;

    }
```